# Cached Ruby Haml Block returns empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, logic, haml

I'm performing some caching in HAML code that also includes logic:

```
- Rails.cache.fetch('unique_key') do
    some text
    - if false
        more text
```

The initial render works as expected, but subsequent calls return blank.
I suspect the trailing `if` statement is the cause.

Any explanation why this is the case? Any suggestion how to overcome it?

An in-elegant solution that works as expected is to append some trailing dummy block:

```
- Rails.cache.fetch('unique_key') do
    some text
    - if false
        more text
    %div.blank
```

Thank you

Comment: Is `perform_cache` a custom method?

Comment: Hi Yakov -- nope. Is pseudocode for: Rails.cache.fetch -- I updated question to clarify, thx.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looking to cache the complete block, but it appears only the result of logic (if false, i.e. nil) is put into the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The last statement that gets evaluated in the block is `if false`. The result of this statement is `nil`. And this value is stored in the cache. When you add `%div.blank` the result that stored in the cache will be like this `some text\n%div.blank`. I'd use standard helper for views [`cache('key')`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html) it should work fine in both cases.

Comment: Why is nil stored, rather than some text + \n + nil ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out ActionView::Helpers::CacheHelper.cache

Comment: I am not sure but I guess that the content is stored in some buffer and when you call `%div.blank` it gets released but `- if false` just evaluates as `nil`. If you change it to `= if true` you'll see the same text twice.